# Laravel Controller to View using chart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Looking for some help. I'm completely new to laravel and stack overflow so please be gentle. Basically, I'm trying to get data from my controller to match the current question ID. I have four tables, survey, user, questions, answers.

I'm trying to dynamically render a chart for each questions answers on the view page. I can get it to work for "all" answers, just can't seem to get it to work for that answer specifically unless I hard code the question ID. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Controller

```
public function view_survey_answers(Survey $survey, Charts $chart, Answer $answer, Question $question) 

$survey = $survey->load('user.questions.answers');

  $chart = Charts::database($answer->load('survey.question')->get(), 'bar', 'material')
    ->title("Answers by User")
    ->elementLabel("Total")
    ->responsive(0)
    ->groupBy('answers->answer')
    ->labels(['static']);


return view('answer.view', compact('survey', 'chart'));
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class answer extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'answer'
];

protected $table = 'answers';

public function survey(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
}

public function question(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
}
```

Again, any help would be appreciated. I'm sure its something in Eloquent that I'm completely missing.

-M

Comment: What does this method `database` expect as parameters?

Comment: public static function database($data, $type = null, $library = null)
    {
        return new Database($data, $type, $library);
    }

Comment: using [https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts]